# Monitoring SuperSet with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, flask, apache-superset

Having abit of an issue trying to configure Elasticsearch with Apache Superset running within a Docker File, based on the Elastic Doc for flask apm
I've configured the following elastic_apm.py File

```
from elasticapm.contrib.flask import ElasticAPM
from superset import app
import os

app.config['ELASTIC_APM'] = {
    'SERVICE_NAME': os.environ.get("ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME"),
    'SECRET_TOKEN': os.environ.get("ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN"),
    'SERVER_URL': os.environ.get("ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL"),
    'DEBUG': True  # Or False based on environment
}
apm = ElasticAPM(app)
```

However i'm having trouble getting it to ship the metrics to the APM Service for Elastic,
I've tried editing the docker-entrypoint.sh

```
# Unregister instance from SSM on SIGTERM
term_handler() {
    if [ -n "$INSTANCE_NAME" ]; then
        aws ssm deregister-managed-instance --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} --instance-id $(sudo cat /var/lib/amazon/ssm/registration | jq -r .ManagedInstanceID)
        echo "SSM instance Unregistered"
        exit 143; # 128 + 15 -- SIGTERM
    fi
}
trap 'term_handler' SIGTERM SIGINT ERR
python /app/elastic_apm.py


"$@"
```

for testing i'v also added the file to the docker-bootstrap.sh

```
if [[ "${1}" == "worker" ]]; then
  echo "Starting Celery worker..."
  celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app worker -Ofair -l INFO
elif [[ "${1}" == "beat" ]]; then
  echo "Starting Celery beat..."
  celery --app=superset.tasks.celery_app:app beat --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid -l INFO -s "${SUPERSET_HOME}"/celerybeat-schedule
elif [[ "${1}" == "app" ]]; then
  echo "Starting web app..."
  flask run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger --host=0.0.0.0
  python /app/elastic_apm.py
elif [[ "${1}" == "app-gunicorn" ]]; then
  echo "Starting web app..."
  /app/docker/superset-entrypoint.sh
fi
```

superset_config.py

```
from elastic_apm import ElasticAPM


# ------------------------------
# GLOBALS FOR APP Builder Override
# ------------------------------


apm = ElasticAPM()
```

I've tried initizaling the script from the superset_config.py aswell without any joy.

I've tired the above, code snippets i'm expecting Apache Superset to ship metrics to ElasticSearch.